# How to associate on-touch location with Data Point in a Graph in android?

Tags: android, graph, point, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to be able to select and drag to modify a point of a graph. First i needed to know if there was a way to associate a touch with targeting a specific point on the graph.

Comment: maybe this help you https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: The action event isn't the problem. I'm unsure of how to get the touch-listener to recognize it's on a point in the Graph.

Comment: is the Graph present like [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) or subclass? You can set onTouchListener just for Graph view. Or I didn't understand an answer.

Comment: I'm trying something more similar to attaching an onTouchListener to a data point, not the graph as a whole. Thus, when someone touches and moves their finger while on a point, the data point moves with their finger.

Comment: Do you want to drag and drop the Graph view?

Comment: Maybe this help you https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: Not the graph view. I want the onTouchListener for an Action.Down to identify and select a single data point that is inside the whollistic Graph view. The point inside the graph should change it's (x,y) coordinate based on the end result of a Drag-and-drop.

Comment: You may to split your Graph to "The point" views, make hierarchy of views  where Graph is the view container and each point presents like child separate view, after that you can attach onTouchListener to each point and drag-and-drop them (points).